# Let a function $f$ be differentiable at $3$ and satisfy $f(3)=3f'(3)>0$. Then find the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{f(3+\frac 3x)}{f(3)})^x.$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be a function differentiable at $3$ and sayisfying $f(3)=3f'(3)>0$. Then find the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{f(3+\frac 3x)}{f(3)})^x.$$

The thing is, I managed to solve the problem. I will give the detailed steps how I solved it:

We observe that $$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{f(3+\frac 3x)}{f(3)})^x,$$ is of the form $1^\infty.$ So, we try a popular recommended transformation, as $$L=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\frac{f(3+\frac 3x)}{f(3)}-1)}\implies e^{\frac 1{f(3)}\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))}.$$ We focus on the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3)).$ We assume $\frac 1x=k$ and as $x\to\infty$ we have, $k\to 0.$ So, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}.$$ We note that $f'(3)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}\color{blue}{=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+3h)-f(3)}{3h}}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+3k)-f(3)}{3k}$ so, we write, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}=3f'(3).$$ Hence, $$L=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\frac{f(3+\frac 3x)}{f(3)}-1)}\implies e^{\frac 1{f(3)}\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))}=e^{\frac{3f'(3)}{f(3)}}=e^{\frac{3f'(3)}{3f'(3)}}=e.$$

---

I hope my solution is correct. But the thing I am confused about is with my  approach. In my solution, I wrote a part $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}"$$ and a part $$"f'(3)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}\color{blue}{=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+3h)-f(3)}{3h}}".$$ But the thing is, just like  $$"f'(3)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h}\color{blue}{=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(3+3h)-f(3)}{3h}}",$$ if I wrote $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}"$$ instead of, $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}",$$ my solution would be erroneous as the transformation $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}"$$ is not valid. But my question, is, why this is so? Why could I write, $$"f'(3)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}\color{blue}{=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+3k)-f(3)}{3k}}",$$ and considered this transformation, to be a logical step and $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}"$$ to be a faulty transformation (when we are basically, doing the analogous thing in both the cases, i.e as $k\to 0$ then we must have $3k\to 0$ and so, we might replace all the $k$'s in the limit expression with $3k's$ as both $k$ and $3k$ are approaching the same thing) ?

### My understanding:

My understanding that of why $$"f'(3)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}\color{blue}{=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+3k)-f(3)}{3k}}",$$ is a valid transformation ?

We note, here $k\to 0$ and hence $3k\to 0$ and the limit expression i.e $\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}$ (before transformation), has all the $k's$ approaching to zero, and as $3k$ approaches zero as well, it doesn't really matter if we replace all the $k's$ in $\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}$ by $3k$ and write, $$f'(3)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}\color{blue}{=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+3k)-f(3)}{3k}},$$ due to which, $f'(3) $ is invariant due to this transformation.

---

By the same preceding logic, why can't I argue about the correctness of this $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}$$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I wrote $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}"$$ instead of, $$"\lim_{x\to\infty}x(f(3+\frac 3x)-f(3))=\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}",$$ my solution would be erroneous

Firstly, it is correct that
$$\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{blue}{=3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}$$

Secondly, as you said, it is wrong that
$$\color{green}{\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}\color{red}{=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}$$
The reason is as follows.

Let $g(k):=\frac 1k(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))$.

Then, we have $$\lim_{k\to 0}g(k)=\lim_{3k\to 0}g(3k)=\lim_{3k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ \color{red}{3\cdot 3k})-f(3))$$

---

**Added** :

It is correct that $$\displaystyle\color{blue}{3\lim_{k\to 0}\frac 1{3k}(f(3+ 3k)-f(3))}=3f'(3).$$ More precisely, the statement $$"f'(3)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+k)-f(3)}{k}\color{blue}{=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(3+3k)-f(3)}{3k}}"$$ is true, because

if $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to 0}\square=0$, we can say $$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x_1+\square)-f(x_1)}{\square}=f'(x_1)$$

Comment: A tiny question: "if $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to 0}\square=0$, we can say $$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x_1+\square)-f(x_1)}{\square}=f'(x_1)$$ " - Is this a standard/well-known fact? Of course, this seems more than obvious to me , but just felt a bit curious.

Comment: @StephenSmith : Yes, it is. We use **the idea** very often. For example, we get $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin(x/2)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}=1$.

Comment: That's so true!

Comment: I think the proof of this often used idea, follows from the definition of derivatives. Is it so ?

Comment: @StephenSmith : Yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks! It's understandable .